# Visual Studio Code Python import error

Tags: python, import, visual-studio-code, package, beautifulsoup

I am trying a simple application. However, I cannot import BS4 from VS.Code. I have tried uninstalling, re-installing, checking the paths etc. I am now stuck. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Please see screenshot:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\workarea\dev\test> & c:/APPS/Python35-32/python.exe c:/workarea/dev/test/bs4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/workarea/dev/test/bs4.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "c:\workarea\dev\test\bs4.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup'
PS C:\workarea\dev\test> & c:/APPS/Python35-32/python.exe c:/workarea/dev/test/hello.py
['c:\\workarea\\dev\\test', 'C:\\APPS\\Python35-32\\python35.zip', 'C:\\APPS\\Python35-32\\DLLs', 'C:\\APPS\\Pytho
n35-32\\lib', 'C:\\APPS\\Python35-32', 'C:\\APPS\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Import not working from VS code however it works fine from cmd line.
[image]

Comment: What happens if inside of the vscode terminal you first do `cd C:\APPS\Python35-32` and then try to import the file from the python command line?

Comment: that works, if I cd into c:\APPS\Python35-32 first then run python it works inside vs command line

Comment: Have you tried setting your PATH environment variable to include the python path?

Comment: Thanks, python was in the path however it works when I added PYTHONPATH,

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect confirmed by VS code.